# CreateService get error: ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS (0x000001e7)

Tags: c++, winapi, service

plz help me this problem:

I create a basic service in this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

PWSTR pszServiceName;
PWSTR pszDisplayName; 
DWORD dwStartType;
PWSTR pszDependencies; 
PWSTR pszAccount;
PWSTR pszPassword;

#define MAX_PATH 100

void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager = NULL;
    SC_HANDLE schService = NULL;

    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)) == 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"GetModuleFileName failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Open the local default service control manager database
    schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | 
        SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
    if (schSCManager == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"OpenSCManager failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Install the service into SCM by calling CreateService
    schService = CreateService(
        schSCManager,                   // SCManager database
        pszServiceName,                 // Name of service
        pszDisplayName,                 // Name to display
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS,           // Desired access
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,      // Service type
        dwStartType,                    // Service start type
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,           // Error control type
        szPath,                         // Service's binary
        NULL,                           // No load ordering group
        NULL,                           // No tag identifier
        pszDependencies,                // Dependencies
        pszAccount,                     // Service running account
        pszPassword                     // Password of the account
        );
    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"CreateService failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    wprintf(L"%s is installed.\n", pszServiceName);

Cleanup:
    // Centralized cleanup for all allocated resources.
    if (schSCManager)
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        schSCManager = NULL;
    }
    if (schService)
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        schService = NULL;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get error: CreateService failed w/err 0x000001e7 (I only know it is: ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS) - but I don't known what is exactly mean, and how to fix.

Anyone plz help me.

Comment: What exactly is the mystery in an error result with the terms INVALID and ADDRESS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the exception of the `schSCManager` and `szPath` variables, *all* of the other variables you are passing to `CreateService()` have not been initialized, they contain random values.  That is especially important for the `psz...` variables, because they are pointers, so you are effectively passing random memory addresses to `CreateService()`.  That is why you are getting an `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` error.

**You need to initialize your variables!**

`pszServiceName` needs to point at a null-terminated string containing the desired service name.

`pszDisplayName` needs to point at a null-terminated string containing the desired service display name.

`dwStartType` needs to contain a valid start type integer value.

`pszDependencies` needs to either be NULL, or point at a double-null-terminated string containing a list of null-separated service names that your service depends on.

`pszAccount` needs to either be NULL or point at a null-terminated string containing the desired user account that the service runs under.

`pszPassword` needs to either be NULL or point at a null-terminated string containing the password for the `pszAccount` account.

**Edit:** You are better off simply getting rid of the variables altogether and pass the desired values directly to `CreateService()`. Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH+1];
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager = NULL;
    SC_HANDLE schService = NULL;

    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)) == 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"GetModuleFileName failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Open the local default service control manager database
    schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
    if (schSCManager == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"OpenSCManager failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Install the service into SCM by calling CreateService
    schService = CreateService(
        schSCManager,                   // SCManager database
        L"Win32_Service,                // Name of service
        L"My Service,                   // Name to display
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS,           // Desired access
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,      // Service type
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,           // Service start type
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,           // Error control type
        szPath,                         // Service's binary
        NULL,                           // No load ordering group
        NULL,                           // No tag identifier
        NULL,                           // No Dependencies
        L"NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService",  // Service running account
        NULL                            // No Password of the account
        );
    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"CreateService failed w/err 0x%08lx\n", GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    wprintf(L"Service is installed.\n");

Cleanup:
    // Centralized cleanup for all allocated resources.
    if (schService)
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        schService = NULL;
    }
    if (schSCManager)
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        schSCManager = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I also edit as your advise:
lstrcpyW(pszServiceName, L"Win32_Service");
 lstrcpyW(pszDisplayName, L"My Service"); 
 dwStartType = SERVICE_DEMAND_START;
 lstrcpyW(pszDependencies,L""); 
 lstrcpyW(pszAccount, L"NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService");
 pszPassword = NULL;

    But it still that error !!!

Comment: @Thuy Duong: Why you redefine MAX_PATH? Maybe you have longer name and than CreateService failed.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I edit as your advise but still that error, why ?

Comment: @ThùyDương: you cannot use lstrcpyW() to copy a string to memory you have not allocated yet. You are better off simply getting rid of the variables altogether and pass the desired values directly to CreateService().

Comment: @ThùyDương this answer is correct in *many* ways. You would do yourself a significant service to learn (a) the C++ language, (b) Windows programming in-general, and (c) Windows Service programming, before slurping example code off the web and just hacking away to make it "work". Without understanding what you're doing, you're not engineering; you're literally *guessing*. (and +1 on the answer, Remy)

Comment: Thanks you very much to RemyLebeau and @WhozCraig, I will learn about Windows Service programming !!!